# HostingEnvironment does not contain definition for QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am trying to call a method asynchronously from a method as below

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async cancellationToken =>
                {
                    await this.DomainLogicUnitOfWork.VehicleInfoManager.CreateOrUpdate(Entity, EntityId);
                });
```

But it is showing me Compile error as below
"HostingEnvironment does not contain definition for QueueBackgroundWorkItem" I am using Net Framework 4.5.1

[image]

Any help please

Comment: What framework version are you using?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5.1

Comment: You propably already notice that it was not avaiable before 4.6